# How to Monitor before_filter and before_action metrics in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, metrics, before-filter

I have a rails app with nearly a hundred `before_filter` and `before_action` calls made and scattered across dozens of controllers. I'm wondering if there is a way I can insert some middleware between filters to record time duration those filters are taking to process.

Are there any gems/tools/libraries/ or general techniques that would help narrow down which filters are taking the longest time to execute?

Comment: Bit dirty and not comprehensive but you could put in every before_action custom log message like this `logger.info("BEFORE ACTION")`  and then trace in logs which ones are executed and how long it takes them